# set label1.text as image name & show image c#

Tags: c#, label

I have a project with SQlite database. I've saved images in folder " pics " ( into debug folder) & their name in the database ( column "docpic") .I set the `label10` text as image name . how can I use `label.text` as image name (that saved in database) and show image in a picturebox ?

`label.text = image.jpg and image name=image.jpg`

infect I want to use `label10.text` as a imagename .

`label10` click event :

```
 private void label10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap("\\scan\\" + label10.Text + ".jpg");       


    }
```

Gridview click event :

```
private void Grid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        i = Convert.ToInt32(DT.Rows[Grid.CurrentRowIndex]["id"]);

        btnDel.Enabled = true;
        btnEdit.Enabled = true;

        label10.Text = DT.Rows[Grid.CurrentRowIndex]["docpic"].ToString();

    }
```

Comment: Show us the code you have tried, explain to us the steps you've already taken...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
picturebox.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\...\" + label10.text, true);
```

Just replace the "`C:\...\`" with the path to the image.

A better approach will be to use the value from the database, you don't really need to put the image as a text label:

```
picturebox.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\...\" + <value from DB>, true);
```

Or in your case:

```
picturebox.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\...\" + DT.Rows[Grid.CurrentRowIndex]["docpic"].ToString(), true);
```

Comment: thank you .. just can you write an example for <value from DB> . i save my image names in column picdoc

Comment: i voted friend . excuseme for this quension , because im beginner . my images is in  folder "scan" thats into folder debug of my project .(debug\scan) . how i must use this instead @"C:\...\"